# Sharepoint ImageMap Editor

Tags: 2010

In the Sharepoint 2010 editor, is there an option to insert ImageMaps? If you look at Telerik's editor: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx
and select the "Full set of tools" on the right hand side you have the ability to create ImageMaps.

This seems like quite an easy thing to automate as it just produces the HTML code to embed an image map. Why doesn't the sharepoint editor have this functionality when it's competitor's are able to offer it?

Comment: You should rephrase to a proper question, such as what are options for creating image maps, or similar if that is what you are after.

Comment: A more accessible way to implement links over a portion of an image is to use CSS to absolutely position an anchor/link tag over a div whose background is set to your image.

Comment: You absolutely *CAN* create an image map with SharePoint Designer 2010:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/08/11/creating-an-image-map-in-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint, like almost every product Microsoft delivers is a platform.  MS makes money by enabling a very large community to make money building solutions on their platform.

Additionally,  MS does market research to decide what elements go into each iteration of its software.  There probably is not a lot of request for image maps.

There are plenty of offline tools free and paid that can create HTML images maps.  You could them upload them into share point and utilize a WVP or CEWP to show utilize your creation.